# Jekyll - Add custom page

Tags: jekyll

I want to add some custom pages under a different folder, not the `_posts`

I want to use `_doc` inside I have multiple files.

```
_doc
 |_installation.md
 |_configure.md
 |_uninstall.md
```

I tried this. But when I hit the URL I got 404 error.

#### installation.md file in _doc folder

```
---
layout: post
date: 2020-06-06 22:00:00 +0530
title: DOC for installation
description: DOC for installation
categories:
- doc
tags:
- doc
permalink: /doc/installation
---

Rest of the content goes here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im able to solve this.

Just add the `_doc` in config file.

```
include: ['_doc']
```